# Should I buy the 2 year Apple Care, for my Macbook Pro with faulty butterfly switches?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, warranty

The class-action lawsuit is ongoing

I have a late 2017 Macbook Pro that has various stuck butterfly switches, since I use an external keyboard most of the time, I didn't even attempt to get it fixed and ruin my life

But my 1-year warranty is about to expire, and I can't decide whether I should purchase the extended warranty or not

There are many things to consider:

1) Lawsuit could miraculously fail, I would be out of warranty

2) Lawsuit could succeed, a fix would be impossible, they would replace the devices, then, would the extended warranty apply to the new device?

3) I purchase the warranty, waste more money on Apple - so better not purchase it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keyboard failing is your only concern, that is not a reason to spring for Apple Care, as Apple has announced an extended Repair program that will cover your 2017 laptop longer than Apple Care would anyway. I would not make a decision based on the worry that Apple is going to replace your whole machine as a result of a lawsuit within the next 2 years; to my knowledge such a replacement program would be unprecedented.

Apple Repair Program: https://www.apple.com/support/keyboard-service-program-for-macbook-and-macbook-pro/

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this extension, I'll probably get it repaired once before selling the device - it eased my mind

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's too late to buy AppleCare for you MacBook Pro. From [Apple's MacBook AppleCare](https://www.apple.com/support/products/mac.html) page:

> Purchase AppleCare+ with your new Mac. Or buy it within 60 days of your Mac purchase:

If you are at all concerned about the faulty switch, you should get it to Apple before the one year warranty runs out.

Comment: Interesting. I had not noticed that Apple no longer sells the standard AppleCare protection plan for MacBooks. Only AppleCare+, which has the accidental damage coverage but as you note requires it be added within 60 days.

Comment: You can still get AppleCare online in many cases. Call and ask for a quote. You don’t get the + if you miss that window, but there may be a window for the normal agreement. Many third parties offer service plans as well. Some even let you bring it to apple for repair.

Comment: Interesting, back when I originally researched it, I recall it being 1 years from the purchase date, but indeed it could be a +/non+ thing

Answer (score 0):

Since you’re not even going to seek a repair under warranty, I can’t see you be happy pre-paying for a repair which is what Apple Care is.

> You’re betting you’re going to pay for one repair over three years and that Apple is going to need to make more than one repair so you win financially.

I know a lot of people that buy AppleCare because they’re paying for peace of mind, so you might consider that even if you’ll never seek a keyboard repair. Flat rate mail in repairs cost about $300 assuming no external damage happens prior to seeking a repair.

I have never seen one Apple related legal settlement be worth a hill of beans once the lawyers take their cut.

Apple offers repair extension programs way before anything ever goes to court, so that’s the real consumer relief I see when Apple decides to extend the warranty and pay for repairs for products.  Apple has already announced this for many MacBook keyboards so you can make your decision based on that today without waiting for a lawsuit to work its way through the court system or trying to “read the tea leaves” like I’ve done above.